# Searching through Arraylist In Java for particular pattern

Tags: java, search, arraylist, find, pattern-matching

Consider I have an Arraylist which holds products name like

```
Dell Inspiron Laptop
Apple iPad
Samsung S4
```

I want to have a search like if one searches for `S4`, it returns `Samsung S4`. I tried to find the answer in many websites but didn't get one. I used .matches and .contains but was of no use.

Comment: Post the code that you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the product names list, assume the variable for product name is **name**, which is a String type.

You can use `if (name.contains(value)) {` or `if(name.indexOf(value)!=-1){` to check whether the name contains the value to be searched.

Have a try with the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> prodNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    prodNames.add("Dell Inspiron Laptop");
    prodNames.add("Apple iPad");
    prodNames.add("Samsung S4");

    // Search S4 and it will print Samsung S4 in Console
    System.out.println(search("S4", prodNames));
}

public static String search(String value, List<String> prodNames) {
    for (String name : prodNames) {
        if (name.contains(value)) {
            return name;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write an utility function like below, that scans through contents of list for particular pattern. Hope this works for your.

```
public static void findMatch(List<String> listNames, String searchTerm){

        for(String inName:listNames){
            if(inName!=null)
                if(inName.contains(searchTerm))
                    System.out.println(" Match Found for "+inName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
public List<String> matches (List<String> dataList, String matchStr){
  List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
  if (matchStr != null) {
    matchStr = matchStr.toLowerCase();
    for(String d : dataList){
      if (d.toLowerCase().contains(matchStr)) {
        result.add(d);
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all clean up the definition of the Array.  I'm guessing that it actually looks like this:

```
{ "Dell Inspiron", "Apple iPad", "Samsung S4" }
```

Then go run this in your IDE :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class TestSearching {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();
        products.add("Dell Inspiron");
        products.add("Apple iPad");
        products.add("Samsung S4");

        System.out.println("Matches to S4 : " + findMatches(products,"S4"));
    }

    public static List<String> findMatches(List<String> products, String searchTerm) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String product : products) {
            if ( product.contains(searchTerm) ) result.add(product);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to do a lookup on the string after the first space, then maybe you don't want to use an ArrayList

Maybe you should use a `Map<String, String>` of product, full name e.g. `"S4", "Samsung S4"`
Then lookups will be much faster.